# c++ Compression library - Deflate or Gzip

Tags: c++, compression

I'm looking for a useful compression library for c++ (on windows)

I need preferably Deflate or Gzip, and i need it to be compatible with .NET's System.IO.Compression.

Also if it will give me a decorator over a stream that would be great so i could do:

```
std::ostringstream stringStream;
CompressionStream cs(stringStream);
cs << object;
cs.flush();
magicalThingy.Send(stringStream.str());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on Boost.Iostream that provides such filter allowing to compress std::iostream 
to gzip or zlib formats (they acutally use zlib under the hood but have nicer interface).

These formats are standard so anybody (.Net too) should open them,

Answer (score 1):

I used ZLib, it was compatible enough.